# Configuring File Associations in Ubuntu with Wine

Tags: ubuntu, files, windows, wine

Related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60716/optimal-setup-for-windows-linux-sharing-and-partitioning) question, I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I downloaded PlayOnLinux 4.1.9 (the Precise version) and used it to install Microsoft Office 2010 Pro. PlayOnLinux downloaded Wine 1.5.21 and whatever else it needed to install office. I did a customized installation and it seems to work fine. The only issue is now that I can't quite get file associations to work correctly. So for example, if I have a .docx document, I want to be able to just double click it and have it open with Microsoft Word. When I try to do that I get an error saying "IOPL not enabled" and the document never opens. I googled it and everyone said to open up wine configuration, go to libraries, add gdiplus and edit it to "Native (Windows)" but this still hasn't fixed the problem. I have no idea what this is or how it is supposed to work but can someone who does, please help. Currently I have to start Word and then use it to open up the document. That works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by creating a small script and then associating it with that file type via 'Open with '. This is available in most desktop environments by rightclicking on one .docx file for example and using the upcoming menu.

Examples and details on how to create such a script can be found in the ubuntu documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine#Creating_file_associations

Comment: That script won't work with software installed using PlayOnLinux, since PoL does not use the default wine prefix (it actually does not even use the default wine executable, it downloads and configures a whole new wine for each app).

Comment: It is also a useless script for "vanilla" wine, since wine already creates `.desktop` file associations for all files registered by an installed windows software, so `.docx` would already be in the "Open with" list of any desktop environments that follow the freedesktop standard file association

Comment: (not to mention that is a very poorly written script... in only 5 lines it manages to break about a dozen shell scripting good practices and conventions... `$*`, `exit 0`, cap (useless) vars, ewww)

Answer (score 0):

Are your `.docx` files marked as executable?

(you can check this by right-clicking the file and going Properties > Permissions > Execute checkbox)

Does `.doc` files open fine when double-clicked?

If you answer 'yes' to both questions, [you may be experiencing this](http://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/linux/faq/cxofficejavaassociation), which is related to [this nasty bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1172961).

Disabling `jar` using `update-binfmts`, as suggested in both links, works great as a permanent fix, but it is also quite technical and a bit intrusive.

A simpler workaround is to *uncheck* the executable permission in your files. Not, however, that this will not work for files in NTFS or FAT partitions, which is a very common scenario for windows-related files such as `docx`. If so, you could try re-mounting your NTFS drive using the `noexec` mount option, which will effectively disable execution permission for all files and thus allow `docx` files to be *opened* rather than *executed* (which does not work anyway, since documents are not binary executables)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it created a scrip file for every file type that each particular office program handles.  So for example there is one for Word to open .doc and .docx .  It was quite nice of PoL to do this however when using the open with menu there are a dozen or so different entries for each office aplication yet they only have the title of the main program but not the extension that is directly asociated.

[image: Select Application list window]

Comment: Do you have an answer to the question?  It looks like you’re just saying that you also have the problem.